# Create a typebox schema where properties can be validated using values given at runtime

Tags: typescript, jsonschema, ajv, typebox

Let's say we have a typescript interface:

```
interface RangedNumber: {
   value: number;
   minValue: number;
   maxValue: number;
}
```

I could generate this type from the following typebox schema:

```
const Schema = Type.Object({
  value: Type.Number(),
  minValue: Type.Number(),
  maxValue: Type.Number(),
});

type RangeNumber = Static<typeof Schema>;
```

Above schema would of course only validate the types of each property.

I know I can pass `minimum` and `maximum` to `Type.Number()`:

```
value: Type.Number({ minimum: x, maximum: y }),
```

But I only know the values for min and max at runtime.

Anyone has ideas what the best approach would be to create such a custom schema using typebox so that:

- The following sample should validate:

```js
{
   value: 5,
   minValue: 0,
   maxValue: 10,
}
```

- while the following sample should not validate:

```js
{
   value: 200,
   minValue: 0,
   maxValue: 10,
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use something like:
`const CreateMinMaxSchema = (min: number, max: number) => t.Object({value: t.Number({ minimum: min, maximum: max })});`?
If you know only know min, max at runtime, then you would need to dynamically construct the schema.

Comment: @OliverFunk we are validating data where for each request the min and max value my be different. So we cannot use those minumun and maximum fields that currently existing for Type.Number.

Unless we could somehow use a reference to another field of the same schema there.